# Vscode enter does not work for a moment when I save file using ctrl+s?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Vs code to write latex. My OS is Win10. Every time when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save my file, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not work for a moment. If I click the <kbd>Enter</kbd> for $k$ times, it will react $k$ times a moment later. But it does not work immediately. Instead, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> works the moment I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save my file.

Also, the user snippets do not work for the moment too!

I want to know what's the problem here?

Comment: are you using any latex extensions in VS Code? have you registered any code action to happen on save? have you turned auto-format-on-save on?

Comment: @starball Thank you for your comment. I use Latex Workshop in VSCode. I've turned auto-format-on-save off. I don't know how to register the code action to happen on save.